# Cannot install Windows 7 gadgets (third party) from a laptop I bought in Thailand?

Tags: windows-7, locale, desktop-gadget

I bought a laptop at an official Acer store in Thailand. It has Windows 7 Premium on it and the locale setting is English (United States). However I noticed that I am unable to upgrade to another version of Windows 7 via online as it recognizes that I am in Thailand somehow. I currently am in Thailand so my external IP would certainly show that. I also notice that third party windows gadgets from addgadgets.com fail to install with an "Unspecified Error". Could this error be due to some internal local setting?

Side note: Windows, as an operating system, has some pretty nasty bugs cross international scenarios. I had to completely reformat this laptop because it was defaulting to a thai keyboard on User password entry. And my password was in English, it was **impossible** to switch to an English keyboard anywhere in the "ease of access" menu.

Comment: I RECOGNIZED THAT. MAY BE DIFFERENCE BETWEEN RTM AND ENTERPRISE EDITIONS! GADGETS WORKS IN RTM BUT NOW WE COULDN'T ADD THEM.

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi: Why are you SHOUTING? Is your Caps Lock key broken?

Comment: sorry ! my caps is LOCKED undesirable . and I dont know what its mean. thanks